# Google Form created with script when Form updated new Sheet data is written to right of prev columns

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a form that's updated by running a script.        I    need to dynamically update the drop down list items. The script removes all form items and then recreates the form items.

I tried removing just the drop down list item with    this code, but it removed all items. So instead I tried removing and recreating all form items.    My current script is further down in this post.

```
    var items = form.getItems();
    for (var i in items) {
    if (Logger.log(items[i].getTitle() == 'For Customer (name) or Finished Goods')) {
         form.deleteItem(items[i]);
    // form.deleteItem(i); didn't delete either
    break;
    }
    }


The form works in that it saves data to the Sheet. The problem is when I rerun the script, and then submit another form, new columns are created in the Google Sheet to the right of the previous columns with the same column names (as the ones on the left) recreated too. See the attached Form and Sheet screenshot.

I think the problem may be that the items are recreated and may have a different item id ? It there a way to specify that the data is saved to the first left-most columns ?

My ultimate goal is to update the customer and product list dynamically - perhaps from a database, or from a Sheet that is updated via a URL CSV file (with the CSV generated hourly on the website via a cron job.

I did look before posting but didn't find an answer.
[enter image description here][1]
Here's my script. Maybe there's a better way. Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

     function updateForm() {
            var form = FormApp.openByUrl(
             'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1-the-urlt'
             );
     FormApp.getUi()

    /* delete all items and recreate */
     var items = form.getItems();
    for (var i in items) {
        // Logger.log(items[i].getTitle() + ': ' + items[i].getId());
             form.deleteItem(items[i]);
    }



    form.addDateItem()
            .setTitle('Date Product was Manufactured');

    // now add a new customer list
    var ProductItem = form.addListItem();
     ProductItem.setTitle('Product')
             .setChoices([
                     ProductItem.createChoice('Aquacide'),
                     ProductItem.createChoice('Bromax'),
                     ProductItem.createChoice('Guardian'),
                     ProductItem.createChoice('Pro Guard'),
             ]);



     form.addTextItem()
        .setTitle('Batch Size (gal) made');

     form.addTextItem()
        .setTitle('Batch/Lot Number');

     form.addTextItem()
        .setTitle('Made By');



    var customerItem = form.addListItem();
     customerItem.setTitle('For Customer (name) or Finished Goods')
             .setChoices([
                     customerItem.createChoice('ABC Inc'),
                     customerItem.createChoice('Imx Corp'),
                     customerItem.createChoice('New Company'),
                     customerItem.createChoice('One More'),
                     customerItem.createChoice('Scream Inc'),
                     customerItem.createChoice('Z Tech')
             ]);
     form.addTextItem()
        .setTitle('Plant Operator pH Reading')
        .setHelpText('NOTE: Take reading when product is finished blending. Take reading of each Drum/Batch made');

     form.addTextItem()
        .setTitle('Tech Dir pH Reading')
        .setHelpText('NOTE: Must verify pH reading for 3022');

    Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
    Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());

    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZx27.png
```

======= Here's the working code with 2 drop down lists created =====

```
function updateForm() {
    var form = FormApp.openByUrl(
     'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1-yourURLhere/edit'
     );
 FormApp.getUi()

var items = form.getItems();
  for (var i in items) {
    var title = items[i].getTitle()

    if (title == 'Product') {
      var listItem = items[i].asListItem()
      var choices = []
      choices.push(listItem.createChoice("Aquacide"))
      choices.push(listItem.createChoice("Bromax"))
      choices.push(listItem.createChoice("Guardian"))
      choices.push(listItem.createChoice("Z-Blend"))
      listItem.setChoices(choices)


  }  // product
  else if (title == 'For Customer (name) or Finished Goods') {
      var custItem = items[i].asListItem()
      var custChoices = []
      custChoices.push(custItem.createChoice("ABC Inc"))
      custChoices.push(custItem.createChoice("BMC Corp"))
      custChoices.push(custItem.createChoice("IDX Inc"))
      custChoices.push(custItem.createChoice("Z-Test Inc"))
      custItem.setChoices(custChoices)

  }  // Customer
}    // for loop



Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());

}
```

Comment: I think you need to skip using linked spreadsheets and instead write a custom onFormSubmit handler (a script bound to the form not the spreadsheet) to deal with passing respondent data to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it.

Comment: In the customer choices, you have used `listItem` at two places, it should be `custItem.` The lines that are incorrect`custChoices.push(listItem.createChoice(title))`  and `listItem.setChoices(custChoices)` both should be `custlItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are deleting all the items is because of this following statement

```
if (Logger.log(items[i].getTitle() == 'For Customer (name) or Finished Goods'))
```

it should be

```
Logger.log(items[i].getTitle() == 'For Customer (name) or Finished Goods')
if (items[i].getTitle() == 'For Customer (name) or Finished Goods')
```

The Logger.log function returns a none empty object back that is always considered true by the if statement. Hence, the if statement always executes, deleting all the form elements

Also, instead of deleting choices you can just add new as described below. The old ones will be replaced and since you are only updating your old item (no new item id) and you won't get a new column.

The final code for updating choices:

```
var items = form.getItems();
  for (var i in items) {
   if (items[i].getTitle() == 'For Customer (name) or Finished Goods') {
      var listItem = items[i].asListItem()
      var choices = []
      choices.push(listItem.createChoice("Option1"))
      choices.push(listItem.createChoice("Option2"))
      choices.push(listItem.createChoice("Option3"))
      listItem.setChoices(choices)


   break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Jack thank you very much.The code is much more simplified. I tried to add the product drop down. Now the Product drop down gets updated with the Customer items and Customer doesn't get updated. I'm probably just being dumb as a stump today. I did remove the breaks and tried a few things. Would you mind taking a look ? I'll post the code and a screenshot.

Comment: @rcdev Please update your question by using Edit link at the end of your question. Also update your code please, thanks

Comment: Thanks I just did it.

Comment: Jack, thanks for your help. I got the code working for 2 drop downs and posted it.